# do not interrupt app when there is a text/incoming call

Tags: android

AFAIK, the Android OS sends the app to background thread when there is an incoming call or text and resumes the app when the call is ended. Is it possible to override this behavior? I want my app to take precedence and not be interrupted when there is a call/text. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not only do I feel it isn't possible, But users will simply not put up with such app behavior. Texts, debatably, but certainly phone calls should take precedence over everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If understood your question you should use the class **android.telephony**, that provides you the methods to handle calls and sms.

You can take inspiration from the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html

and in particular to the **TelephonyManager** and its state handling

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: @user678229, did you manage to get your app to avoid being interrupted by incoming phone calls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it isn't. The device is made to receive text and calls, so I remember that I've readed something that said "If you don't declare OnStop() method, your app will crash when a text or call arrive"... it's means you have an obrigation to declare that, and you can't avoid text or calls